# Autotransformer in pst-circ?

Tags: pst-circ

How can i draw a autotransformer with pst-circ, that looks like `\transformer`?
A autotransformer looks like:

[image: Autotransforer]

I tried with a coil, but it does not look like a `\transformer`
[image]

A MWE with the code for the above document is here:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,15)
    \pnodes(3,7){T1P1}(3,3){T1P2}(5,7){T1S1}(5,3){T1S2}
    \pnodes(8,7){T2P1}(8,3){T2P2}(10,7){T2S1}(10,3){T2S2}

    \coil[dipolestyle=curved](T1P1)(T1P2){}
    \psline{->}(4,5)(3.3,5)

    \transformer[primarylabel={230},secondarylabel={5000}](T2P1)(T2P2)(T2S1)(T2S2){$T_2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here comes a "starter":

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-circ,pst-coil}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,15)
    \pnodes(3,7){T1P1}(3,3){T1P2}(5,7){T1S1}(5,3){T1S2}
    \pnodes(8,7){T2P1}(5,5){t2s2}(8,3){T2P2}(10,7){T2S1}(10,3){T2S2}
    \pccoil[coilwidth=0.65,coilheight=0.4](T1P1)(T1P2)
    \pcline[offset=-0.4,nodesep=0.5](T1P1)(T1P2)
    \pcline[offset=-0.5,nodesep=0.5](T1P1)(T1P2)
    \pccoil[coilwidth=0.65,coilheight=0.4](t2s2)(T1S2)
    \psline{<-}(3.3,5)(t2s2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]